# shopify event API is not working for Update Order

Tags: java, shopify

I am synchronizing Shopify Order with my Database using restful APIs and I am using this API

```
https://sapphire-online.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-07/events.json?filter=order&created_at_min=2020...
```

to get event records which are recently updated on shopify.

Result of this:

```
{
    "events": []
}
```

This API is not working except Confirm verb.

as per shopify documentation update event is not working, its returning only Confirm records. I already try Weebhooks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just setup and listen to an orders/update webhook? That actually does work, and you can customize it to only return data you are interested in.

Comment: Can we manage Webhooks in Java Applications,